# ComboBox On DrawItem does'nt work

Tags: delphi, combobox

I want the comboBox Item to change color if the object associated has a certain value.
I did the following:

```
with Control as TComboBox do
  begin
     Canvas.Font.Color:=clBlack;
     Canvas.Brush.Color := clWhite ;
     if TMyObj(MyCb.Items.Objects[MyCb.ItemIndex]).C = 'C' then
        Canvas.Brush.Color := clred ;
     Canvas.FillRect(Rect);
     Canvas.TextOut(Rect.Left, Rect.Top, Items[Index])
 end;
```

I can see all of the Combo items black on White. When I hover with the mouse, all of the items on wich I hover are painted red (even if the C value is not 'C'

Do you understand why ?

Comment: If the combobox in question is called `MyCb`, why do you spell it out even if you have `with Control as TCombobox do` above? To your issue, maybe you intended to use the `Index: integer` argument instead of `ItemIndex`? If not, please provide an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), because I can't reproduce the problem as you describe it (one reason being that `TMyObj` is totally unknown.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. You're repeatedly setting the color based on the ItemIndex, which does not change during the drawing of the item. You should be using the `Index` provided when the method is called as one of the parameters.

```
with Control as TComboBox do
begin
  Canvas.Font.Color := clBlack;
  Canvas.Brush.Color := clWhite ;
  if TMyObj(Control.Items.Objects[Index]).C = 'C' then // Change this line
    Canvas.Brush.Color := clred ;
  Canvas.FillRect(Rect);
  Canvas.TextOut(Rect.Left, Rect.Top, Items[Index])
end;
```

Comment: Yes Ken, perfect. I just had to amend the statement 'Control.Objects..' with 'Items.Objects..', and then it finally works as I expected. Thank you

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I've corrected it so it doesn't confuse anyone in the future. :-)